# SFTP suppress all messages except errors

Tags: bash, sftp

I want to 'put' a file from local system to FTP server using sftp (only) from bash script.

I want to suppress all messages except errors:

```
sftp $user@$server 2>&1 1>/dev/null <<EOF
put $local_file_path $remote_file_path
EOF
```

Output of the command , when successful:

```
Connecting to <server>...
```

Why I am still getting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because `Connecting to <server>...` is sent to file descriptor 2 (stderr). Remember that the only difference between file descriptors 1 (stdout) and 2 (stderr) is that the former is *traditionally* used for normal messages while the latter is *traditionally* used for debug or error outputs. However, the program decides what goes to one channel or the other, you can redirect one output or the other but you cannot decide what is printed where. You cannot enforce for example that only errors go to stderr.

Comment: in other words, I can't do what I want, right?

Comment: @yuris I'm afraid not :(

Answer (score 2):

I did have the same issue so I came up with this solution. It's not 100% the the normal `stderr` output but it helps a lot to determine what caused the error.

```
sftp $user@$server > /dev/null 2>&1 <<EOF
put $local_file_path $remote_file_path
EOF

sftp_status=$?
case $sftp_status in
    0) sftp_error="";;
    1) sftp_error="Error 1: Generic error - Undetermined error in file copy";;
    2) sftp_error="Error 2: Remote host connection failure";;
    3) sftp_error="Error 3: Destination is not directory, but it should be";;
    4) sftp_error="Error 4: Connecting to host failed";;
    5) sftp_error="Error 5: Connection lost for some reason";;
    6) sftp_error="Error 6: File does not exist";;
    7) sftp_error="Error 7: No permission to access file";;
    8) sftp_error="Error 8: Undetermined error from sshfilexfer";;
    9) sftp_error="Error 9: File transfer protocol mismatch";;
    65) sftp_error="Error 65: Host not allowed to connect";;
    66) sftp_error="Error 66: Protocol error";;
    67) sftp_error="Error 67: Key exchange failed";;
    68) sftp_error="Error 68: Host authentication failed";;
    69) sftp_error="Error 69: MAC error";;
    70) sftp_error="Error 70: Compression error (not used in SSH2)";;
    71) sftp_error="Error 71: Service not available";;
    72) sftp_error="Error 72: Protocol version not supported";;
    73) sftp_error="Error 73: Host key not verifiable";;
    74) sftp_error="Error 74: Connection lost";;
    75) sftp_error="Error 75: Disconnected by application";;
    76) sftp_error="Error 76: Too many connections";;
    77) sftp_error="Error 77: Cancelled by user";;
    78) sftp_error="Error 78: No more auth methods available";;
    79) sftp_error="Error 79: Illegal user name";;
    255) sftp_error="Error 255: Error occurred in SSH";;
    *) sftp_error="Unknown sftp Error";;
esac
echo $sftp_error
```

The Status Codes are based on this list: https://support2.microfocus.com/techdocs/2487.html

**What status codes your are getting depends on your sftp client**
So some clients only use status code **0**,**1** & **255**

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame no one ever answered this correctly.

Try:

```
sftp_command 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -v 'Connecting to'
```

Which redirects stderr to stdout and *then* redirects stdout to /dev/null leaving you to display everything other than Connecting to.

Answer (score -1):

> Why I am still getting it?

Because `sftp` prints this message into `stderr`, and you redirected `stderr` to `stdout`, i.e. your terminal, with `2>&1`.

You see, file descriptors like `&1` aren't links (or pointers, if you're familiar with the concept)—they're values. So when you type `2>&1`, what really happens is:

1. Your shell figures out where file descriptor 1 (`stdout`) is pointing at the moment. In your case, you're running this in interactive shell, so `stdout` points to your terminal.
2. File descriptor 2 (`stderr`) is set to your terminal, too.

Thus, when you change first file decriptor later on (with `1>/dev/null`), it has no effect on `stderr` redirection, because `stderr` does't *depend* on `stdout` in any way.

To redirect everything into `/dev/null`, you should consider how values of file descriptors are copied from one another; that will lead you to rearranging redirections like so:

```
sftp $user@$server 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Now your `stdout` is set to `/dev/null`, and then `stderr` is set to the current value of `stdout`, i.e. `/dev/null`. Yay!

Comment: The OP said : "I want to suppress all messages except errors:" so your answer misses the point (although it describes very correctly what is happening).

Comment: I want to keep errors, but don't want the 'Connecting to ' don't understand why it's being sent to error

Comment: Ah, sorry! My bad. Perhaps filter out the unwanted message with `grep -v`, @yuris?

Comment: yes, I know that the only option for me is to manipulate the returned text.

Comment: You can also try `-q`, which will "disable the progress meter as well as warning and diagnostic messages from ssh"; and also `-o LogLevel=ERROR` or maybe even `-o LogLevel=FATAL`.

Comment: -q not supported atleast with my version of sftp

Comment: and  -o  LogLevel= doesn't suppress it

Comment: @yuris OpenSSH's sftp had this flag for [almost seven years](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/commit/?id=46bbbe3326d69a84d94caca656c40a4521c10c45) now. Just a heads up…